# How to put a link on an image rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, hyperlink, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have an image in my header of my app, but i want to make that image a link and i would like to do this in the rails way, because i know how to do it with html/php.

is there such an option for that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use the code like this
`<%= link_to (image_tag "image_name.jpg", :title => 'Image_Title'), :action => :action_name %>`